# Find out where a "#" link is pointing?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, href

I have this link here

```
<a href="#" id="gallery_search"
   data-filter=".<?php echo $Filterclass; ?>"><?php echo strtoupper($ui); ?></a>
```

When you click it, it reloads the page (without refresh) and shows a different result based on what data-filter is.

Pretty simple.

Problem is I'd like to find out where that link leads so I can alter it, and go straight to it.

My domain is http://explorerhinelander.com/rsd    (Wordpress installation)

When I try to go to http://explorerhinelander.com/rsd/#gallery_search it does not load the page in the same way as if you clicked the link. It just reloads whatever is already there.

I just need to know how to get the URL of where that link leads. Firebug shows it's simply "#".

Comment: I can't even find this anchor tag, also there is a bunch of gallery_filter id that are the same

Comment: I think it is an AJAX request because the page reloads without a refresh. It just drives me nuts I can create the link, click the link, but not manually go to it or see it or do anything with it.

Comment: It's not an AJAX request. Firebug shows blank console. How do I find this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in down of page you have next script

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#gallery-bank-thumbnails_3413 > a > div.gb_overlay").addClass("animated overlay");
    jQuery(".imgLiquidFill").imgLiquid({fill: true});
    jQuery("#holder_3413").jPages({containerID: "gallery-bank-thumbnails_3413", perPage:18,animation:"overlay"});
});
var $optionSets = jQuery("#bank_filters_3413"), // container for links
    $optionLinks = $optionSets.find("a"); //find all <a> tags in container
    $optionLinks.click(function () { // add onclick event handler
        var selector_3413 = jQuery(this).attr("data-filter"); //get filter string
        if (selector_3413 != "*") { //if not show all
            jQuery("#gallery-bank-thumbnails_3413 > a > div.margin_thumbs").addClass("jp-hidden"); // hide all
            jQuery("#gallery-bank-thumbnails_3413 > a" + selector_3413 + " > div.margin_thumbs").removeClass("jp-hidden"); // delete class with hide for filtered
            jQuery("#gallery-bank-thumbnails_3413 > a" + selector_3413 + " > div.margin_thumbs").css("display", ""); // show all filtered
        }
        else { //if show all
            jQuery("#gallery-bank-thumbnails_3413 > a > div.margin_thumbs").removeClass("jp-hidden"); //remove class with hide for all
            jQuery("#gallery-bank-thumbnails_3413 > a" + selector_3413 + " > div.margin_thumbs").removeClass("animated overlay"); //remove class with overlay
            jQuery("#gallery-bank-thumbnails_3413 > a > div.margin_thumbs").css("display", ""); // show all
        }
        jQuery("#holder_3413").jPages({containerID: "gallery-bank-thumbnails_3413", perPage:18,animation:"overlay"});
        return false;
    });
    jQuery("#bank_filters_3413 a").on("click", function () {
        jQuery("#bank_filters_3413").find(".act").removeClass("act");
        jQuery(this).addClass("act");
    });
```

in fact this script simple change css for loaded div, without ajax or something like ajax :-)

Comment: Grundy thanks. What amazes me is I searched for 'data-filter' and 'gallery-search' all throughout the plugin code. It didn't turn up.

Comment: I guess the lesson here is VIEW THE SOURCE

Answer (score 0):

That link is being replaced by or controlled by JavaScript.

Search through your code for any links that contain pieces of code that looks like one of these four lines:

```
document.getElementById("gallery_search").onClick = function() { ... }
document.querySelector("#gallery_search").onClick = function() { ... }
document.getElementById("gallery_search").addEventListener('click', function() { ... })
$('#gallery_search').click(function() { ... })
```

It may be the easiest searching all the JavaScript that gets loaded into your site for the term `gallery_search`.

Comment: it also may be some plugin like `$('#gallery_search').gallery({...})`

Comment: @Grundy Looking at the source of the page he linked to, it seems you are correct. It seems to be using some plugin named "Gallery Bank Pro Edition", though I still haven't found where exactly the link is being "picked up" by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'Network' view of FireBug or Google Chrome to inspect the request. On Chrome press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and go to the 'network' tab. Reload the page, click the button, and watch the URL that is being requested.